# Let $p$ be a prime. Determine the number of homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}_p \oplus \mathbb{Z}_p$ into $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $p$ be a prime. Determine the number of homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}_p \oplus  \mathbb{Z}_p$ into $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

---

How can I able to solve this problem?can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 1):

***Hint***: what can $(1,0)$ go to through a homomorphism? What about $(0,1)$?

Comment: $(1,0)$ goes to $p$ and $(0,1)$ goes to $p$.am I right?if I am right then answer must be $p^2$

Comment: The answer's correct, the argumentation I doubt it: why do you think the element $\,(1,0)\,$ **must** be mapped tp $\,p=0\in\Bbb Z_p\,$ ?? That'd make the map the zero map...Is this what you really meant?

Comment: @abdakchi: $(1,0)$ can go to any of the $p$ elements of ${\bf Z}_p$, likewise $(0,1)$; the answer is correct: the value of a homomorphism on $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ determines it uniquely.

Answer (score 1):

One approach:

Show that the group $\,V:=\Bbb Z_p\times \Bbb Z_p\,$ is a vector space of dimension two over the field $\,\Bbb Z_p\,$ (hint: define for $\,k\in\Bbb Z_p\;,\;\;(a,b)\in V\;,\;\;k(a,b):=(a^k,b^k)\,$ , and sum coordinatewise).

Thus, your question is tantamount to find out what's $\,|V^*|\,$ , but we know that in finite dimension $\,V\cong V^*\implies \dim V^*=2\,$ , so...

Answer (score 1):

Let $G=\mathbb{Z}_p^2$ and $H=\mathbb{Z}_p$ and suppose $\varphi:G\rightarrow H$ is a homomorphism.  Define $$\pi_1:G\rightarrow \langle (1,0)\rangle\leqslant G\hspace{45pt}\pi_2:G\rightarrow \langle (0,1)\rangle\leqslant G$$  Writing composition as multiplication and pointwise addition as addition, we observe that $\varphi=\varphi\pi_1+\varphi\pi_2$, so it makes sense to define $\varphi_1=\pi_1\varphi$ and $\varphi_2=\pi_2\varphi$ so that $\varphi=\varphi_1+\varphi_2$.  We see that $\varphi_1,\varphi_2$ are homomorphisms from their respective domains (each isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$) to the codomain $H=\mathbb{Z}_p$.  Since these $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ completely define $\varphi$, we see that $$\left|\operatorname{Hom}_{\operatorname{Grp}}(G,H)\right|=\left|\operatorname{End}(\mathbb{Z}_p)\right|^2$$
There are $p-1$ automorphisms $\theta_n\in\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_p)$, each defined by $\theta_n(x)=n\cdot x$.  Since $\operatorname{Z}_p$ is simple, it has no other nontrivial endomorphisms, so counting the trivial endomorphism, we find $\left|\operatorname{End}(\mathbb{Z}_p)\right|=p$, whence $\left|\operatorname{Hom}_{\operatorname{Grp}}(G,H)\right|=p^2$.

Note that this argument easily generalizes to show that $\left|\operatorname{Hom}_{\operatorname{Grp}}(\mathbb{Z}_p^m,\mathbb{Z}_p)\right|=p^m$.